# When a portal is burned out, is it burned out for everyone?

Tags: ingress

So it seems that if I hack a portal four to five times in a row, I will eventually get a "Portal is burned out..." message and I have to wait for four (?) hours until it resets and I can hack it again.

When it is burned out, can other people still hack it and get things out?  Or does the "burned out" state affect everyone - perhaps even the other faction?

Answer (score 17):

Confirmed: it is only burned out for the player getting the message, all other players can hack the portal.

It takes 5 hacks within 4 hours to burn out the portal, *sometimes* an unsuccessful attempt to hack the portal (hack within 5 minute cool down time) counts toward burning out limit.

Portal will be again available for hacking in 4 hours after the last attempt, hack counter is restarted.

Comment: The above answer only applies when its a normal portal without a multihack. Multihack enables additional hacks before burnout. If i understand correctly then a very rare multihack will add 8 additional hacks onto it meaning 12 total before 4 hr burnout.