# Is portal-burnout only player-specific or global?

Tags: ingress

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [When a portal is burned out, is it burned out for everyone?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/96330/when-a-portal-is-burned-out-is-it-burned-out-for-everyone)

When a portal reports burn-out, is this only for me, or will other players (regardless of faction) be locked out as well?

(No one around to do experiments at the moment.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it is only user specific, we have tested it.

Answer (score 2):

You can only hack the same portal 4 times in a 4 hour period, barring any exploits that used to exist. If you try to hack a 5th time, then only you get the 'Burnout' message, not others who haven't finished their quota.